# How do i find out if a touch is over the frame of another shape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, cgpoint

I know how to get the position touched, so now i have a CGPoint with the touched position. What's the best way to find out if the touch is over a UIView or not? I know of the method of:

```
if touchpoint.x > frame.origin.x && touchpoint.x < frame.size.width + frame.origin.x
```

etc., but is this the best way of going about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to know if a point is inside the bounds of a view, you can use the `pointInside:withEvent:` method.

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [theTouch locationInView:theView];
// If the point was retrieved for a different view, it must be converted to the coordinate space of the destination view using convertPoint:fromView:
if([theView pointInside:touchPoint withEvent:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"point inside");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ugh's answer covers views, which I believe is what you want; if you have an arbitrary `CGRect`, you can use [`CGRectContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint):

```
BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(myRect, touchPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CGRectContainsPoint will save you from writing so many comparision equations.